# Specs2 IT environment tearDown

Tags: scala, integration-testing, specs2

I need some help here... I’m using **specs2** to run my **integration tests**.

So before everything is running, I’m setting up my **simplicators** (fake server my system interact with).

The problem is, that I need to find a way how to know when to shut down these servers once all tests are done.

**After** and **step()** are not good enough as they happen in each individual test scope. What is something that can run after ***all*** tests are done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

[Here is how it is done](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Global+setup/teardown)!

Here is a nice interface to setup an IT environment:

```
trait FakeServer {
  def setup: Unit
  def tearDown: Unit
}

object ITEnvironment extends FakeServer{
  private val simplicators: Seq[FakeServer] = Seq(new FakeWebServer)

  override def setup: Unit = simplicators foreach { server => server.setup}
  override def tearDown: Unit = simplicators foreach { server => server.tearDown}
}

trait Specs2ITEnvironment { this: Specification =>
  sequential
  override def map(fs: =>Fragments) = Step( {ITEnvironment.setup} ) ^ fs ^ Step( {ITEnvironment.tearDown} )
}

class LoginIT extends SpecificationWithJUnit with Specs2ITEnvironment{
    ... your test here ...
}
```